# How do assign different sets of colors to different groups of categories?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that gives color based on the `SalesCategory` in the data frame. Some of these `SalesCategory`s, however, are no longer active and I would like to assign grey colors to the inactive `SaleCategory`s. How do I assign one set of colors to the active categories and annother set of colors to the inactive set? The sample is trivial for this example because you could easily use `scale_fill_manual` for all the cases, but the data behind this request would make that unfeasible because of the number of categories it has.

```
myFrame <- 
    data.frame(Year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
                        2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
                        2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L),
               SalesCategory = c("Bobsleds", "IceSkates", "RollerSkates", "HockeyPucks", "Bobsleds", 
                                 "IceSkates", "RollerSkates", "HockeyPucks", "RollerBlades", "Bobsleds", 
                                 "IceSkates", "RollerSkates", "HockeyPucks", "RollerBlades", "Helmets", 
                                 "Bobsleds", "IceSkates", "RollerSkates", "HockeyPucks", "RollerBlades", 
                                 "Helmets", "Bobsleds", "IceSkates", "RollerSkates", "HockeyPucks", 
                                 "RollerBlades", "Helmets"),
               PctOfSales = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 
                              0, 0.15, 0.15, 0, 0.05, 0.4, 0, 0.35, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.4, 
                              0.2),
               ActiveRevenueStream =c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                                      FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                                      TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))

# this plot gives colors to all the categories indiscriminantly
ggplot(myFrame,(aes(Year,PctOfSales, fill = SalesCategory))) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
  library(RColorBrewer)
  uniq_inactive<-unique(myFrame[myFrame$ActiveRevenueStream==FALSE,"SalesCategory"])
  uniq_active<-unique(myFrame[myFrame$ActiveRevenueStream==TRUE,"SalesCategory"])

  my_active_cols <- brewer.pal(length(uniq_active),"Set1")
  names(my_active_cols)<- uniq_active

  my_inactive_cols <- gray.colors(length(uniq_inactive),start=0.5,end=0.7)
  names(my_inactive_cols) <- uniq_inactive

  my_cols <- c(my_active_cols,my_inactive_cols)

ggplot(myFrame,(aes(Year,PctOfSales, fill = SalesCategory))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + scale_fill_manual(values=my_cols)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.